is there any way to use a standard/built-in terminfo (vt100, ansi, xterm..) for a terminal
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Terminal-emulator.html says

Term mode recognizes and handles ANSI-standard VT100-style escape sequences, which are accepted by most modern terminals

but I seems like they didn't mean that literally because ansi-term uses a TERM value called eterm-color, and it doesn't look like it is a superset of ansi or vt100.
My bigger problem is that I sometimes docker exec -it into docker containers, so it would be nice to have a TERM value that is available in the terminfo database in most containers, but implemented in emacs.
For example if I go into a container and try to read a man page (as an experiment), if I leave TERM=eterm-color then less won't even open (and the terminal doesn't really work) but I have tried setting xterm vt100 and ansi inside the container, and none seem to work perfectly either - which makes sense from looking at infocmp
So what are you supposed to do in a time like this?  I am starting by finding out if there is an emacs terminal that implements xterm or one of the other common ones, or even better a mode for ansi-term.

Most terminals do not adapt themselves to an alternate termcap/terminfo entry (though I do know of one that did, called psterm.) Why can’t you just install the correct terminfo entry into the docker container?

great question... I just look at a lot of docker images that are maintained by other team members, and containers that are already running.  I think I would have to install emacs or upload the terminfo.
